# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError sun.misc.Unsafe with external Jar on Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a Java library jar on Android that uses `sun.misc.Unsafe`. A call to the library throws a

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method ensureClassInitialized(Ljava/lang/Class;)V in class Lsun/misc/Unsafe; or its super classes (declaration of 'sun.misc.Unsafe' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)`

As far as I understood `sun.misc.Unsafe` is not part of the Android API. So I tried to include the `sun.misc.Unsafe` in my app manually (downloaded the file from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/Unsafe.java)). However, the exception is still thrown.

Any ideas, how I can use the library jar on Android?

Comment: The library is asking for trouble by using a class from a `sun.*` package. There is a reason why this should not be done.

Comment: Does that mean the library is not usable on Android? Is there any way to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas, how I can use the library jar on Android?

There is a Android version of `sun.misc.Unsafe` (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/a7752f4d22097346dd7849b92b9f36d0a0a7a8f3/libdvm/src/main/java/sun/misc/Unsafe.java)), but it doesn't include that particular method.  (I assume that the method was introduced in Java 7 ...)

Using the OpenJDK version of `Unsafe` on Dalvik / Android won't work, because it depends on native methods that are not implemented by the Dalvik VM.  (And it looks like you didn't even manage to get Davlik to load the OpenJDK version instead of the Android version.)

Note that some `Unsafe` methods will be usable  on Android... but only the ones in the version of the class I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to rebuild the library from source and take out the calls to ensureClassInitialized. Replace them with allocateInstance, which does the same thing without requiring the class to be concrete or calling a constructor for the throwaway "instance".